# XDocument Load fails even though it can be accessed from chrome

Tags: c#, xml

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all");
```

fails with the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Even though you can access https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all via chrome.

The api page: https://predictit.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/12000001878-does-predictit-make-market-data-available-via-an-api-
mentions appending text to the request header, may be a clue?

> "To change the return type for any of the above, add one of the following to the request header.
>
> Accept: application/xml
>
> Accept: application/json"

I have checked my firewall, visual studio is allowed on both networks.

Comment: So have you added that header to your request?

Comment: So use HttpClient/WebClient/HttpWebRequest to download the XML file, being careful to match the headers sent to those that your browser sends. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is very useful for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that particular error, it's caused by a TLS handshake error.  You can fix it by enabling the appropriate TLS protocols by adding this somewhere in your code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Once you have that sorted, you'll run into other problems with the response. You have to set the accept headers on the request. If you attempt to download without the headers, it will return JSON by default. The browser will include XML as one of the headers so that's why you're seeing XML.

You cannot do that using the basic `XDocument.Load()` overloads. You either have to download the contents separately as a string or at least obtain a stream with the correct headers and use the correct overload.

```
XDocument GetSecureXDocument(string url)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var client = new WebClient
    {
        Headers = { [HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml" }
    };
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        return XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```